# Android (Compose) -> MutableStateOf Changes do not update the UI

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I'm struggling with my app for university and I can't find out why it behaves like it does. I have a EventDetail screen on which the user can join an event. If he does, he gets added to the MutableList Members. I implemented a Membercount on the detail Screen aswell as an if statement to switch the button to leave if the user is already member of the event. Below, you can find a shortened example of the problem. Can somebody tell me what I am doing wrong?

*ViewModel*

```
class EventsViewModel(private val eventRepository: 
EventRepository = EventRepository()) :
ViewModel() {

var eventList = mutableStateOf<MutableList<Event>>(mutableListOf())
var currentEvent = mutableStateOf<Event?>(null)


fun joinEvent() {
    if (currentEvent.value == null) return

    viewModelScope.launch {
        withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {

            val event = eventRepository.joinEvent(currentEvent.value!!)

            currentEvent.value = event
        }
    }
}
}
```

*Composable*

```
fun EventDetailScreen(navController: NavController, eventId: String) {
val viewModel: EventsViewModel = viewModel()
val userViewModel: userViewModel = viewModel()


viewModel.getEvent(eventId)

val event by remember {
    viewModel.currentEvent
}

if (event!!.createdBy != userViewModel.currentUser.value!!.uid)
if (event!!.members.find { it == userViewModel.currentUser.value!!.uid } == null)
    Button_Primary(
    onClick = { viewModel.joinEvent() },
    text = "Join Event",
)
else
    Button_Secondary(
    onClick = { viewModel.leaveEvent() },
    text = "Leave Event",
)`
```

*Event*

```
data class Event(
    val id: String?,
    val title: String,
    val description: String,
    val startDateTime: LocalDateTime,
    val endDateTime: LocalDateTime,
    val location: String?,
    val createdBy: String?,
    val createdAt: LocalDateTime = LocalDateTime.now(),
    var members: MutableList<String> = mutableListOf(),
    val currentIds: MutableList<String> = mutableListOf()
)
```

I already found, that members can be set to MutableStateOf<MutableList> but I thought, that this should only be done in the UI, as I don't want to send a mutableState to Firebase.

I would expect the button to switch to Leave Event after I joined and switch to Join if I left the event. But it only gets updated when I close the screen. I can see the button change to the right state 1 second before i finally leave the screen.

Answer (score 1):

You can't make a working State out of a mutable type like MutableList or your Event class (which is mutable because it has some `vars` and `MutableLists` inside it). Compose cannot detect mutations to these mutable instances. (In general, even without Compose, you would pretty much never combine `var` with a mutable type either because it makes something mutable in two different ways, which is error-prone.) For lists, use `mutableStateListOf` instead of a List inside a MutableState. Inside your Event class, change the `var` to `val` and the MutableLists into read-only Lists.

You should also mark the Event class with `@Immutable` so the read-only Lists won't cause unnecessary recompositions. But it is up to you not to reuse MutableLists as arguments that you pass to the Event constructor, or you are breaking the `@Immutable` contract.

Finally, this code in your composable:

```
val event by remember {
    viewModel.currentEvent
}
```

means that `event` will always be whatever the value of `viewModel.currentEvent` was the first time the function was called, so it can never see newer values. Change it to:

```
val event by viewModel.currentEvent
```

You don't need to remember things that you retrieve from a ViewModel because the ViewModel outlives your UI.

Comment: Hey, first thanks for your answer. If I get it right, I should change the var to val for the members. Did this but i doesn't seem to have any improvement. I also tried to Change the type of eventList to MutableStateList, but it doesn't know that type :/
I can't find a Gradle import for MutableStateList :(

Comment: Use `mutableStateListOf()`. There is no `MutableStateList()` function. Note the lower-case `m`.

Comment: That works, thank you. But I still have the struggle with currentEvent :/

Comment: Oh I see your other problem. See updated answer.

Comment: I would really love to say that this works now, but I have the same behaviour. I click my join button nothing happens. I click the back button, the join button transforms to the leavebutton for a second and then the recent screen appears. Opening the details again shows the right state then. :'(

Comment: Your `joinEvent()` function returns early without doing anything if there isn’t already a `currentEvent`. That looks suspicious. But I can only guess because I’m not seeing all your code and I don’t know the intended behavior.

Comment: Hey, thanks for your afford. After reading all the documentation and chatting with Bard and so on, I recognized, that mutableState is not made to be used inside of a viewModel. I changed the Type to MutableLiveData<Event>() and ObservedAsState in my Composable. Then I had to switch to my Main Dispatcher after fetching the event to update the data. For me as a webdev, that seems completly wrong, but as I undestand the documentation, that is the way it should be done in android :)

Comment: MutableState wasn't made *for* ViewModel, but it works fine and is used in many official Jetpack documentation samples. It shouldn't be the cause of the issue, although personally I think it's good practice to keep State only in Compose code for modularity reasons.